# Parse XML in android development

Tags: android, xml

I am currently using a XMLPullParser to parse XML from Merriam Webster's dictionary API. Everything works fine until I realize there are different child elements for different words. What I mean is for instance, in the XML for "wait", I have

```
<dt>
:a critical examination, observation, or evaluation :
<sx>trial</sx>
</dt>
```

A different word such as "interesting" has

```
<dt>
:holding the attention :arousing
<fw>interest</fw>
</dt>.
```

You notice that the first has a different tag "sx" while the second has "fw". How do I successfully parse the elements to have all the values in "dt" irrespective of child elements?

Thanks.

Comment: When you encounter child elements, look at the element name (`sx`, `fw`, etc.) and decide what to do with the information in that element (hold onto it, discard it, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks. The issue is there could be quite a number of tags that I even have no idea exists. There would be nothing to compare to in that case. I want to get full details irrespective of the inner tag names.

Comment: "The issue is there could be quite a number of tags that I even have no idea exists" -- hopefully their API has documentation. "I want to get full details irrespective of the inner tag names" -- please explain, in programming terms, what "get full details" means. You have two examples in your question. Edit your question and show **exactly** what you are expecting to get as a result of your parsing. Personally, I think you need to build a data model that matches the XML.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Okay. I mean I want to get all the text inside the "dt" tag. Every single text irrespective of the surrounding tag. I did build a data model that matched the xml when I used a particular word for my API call. I noticed I started getting errors when I wanted defintions for other words. It was then I realized my model was too static and there were some tags that appeared for a word and didn't for some other words. Do you understand me now? Thanks

Comment: "Every single text irrespective of the surrounding tag" -- then do that. `XmlPullParser` is event driven. Pay attention to the text events and ignore the nested tag events. "It was then I realized my model was too static and there were some tags that appeared for a word and didn't for some other words" -- so? Leave some fields `null` in your data model. Or use a flexible model (e.g., `HashMap<String, String>` for child elements and their text contents).

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot @CommonsWare.